# URL Rewrite not working on IIS 10.0

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

I'm using URL Rewrite on IIS 10.0 and have the following rule configured at the server level (applicationHost.config). I've tried it in my web.config to no avail as well.

```
   <rewrite>
        <globalRules>
            <rule name="redirect">
                <match url="/admin" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="10.30.*.*" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/error" />
            </rule>
        </globalRules>
    </rewrite>
```

Is there anything immediately obviously wrong here? I want any external traffic trying to hit /admin to get redirected to an error page, and only allow a single internal IP block to access it. Pulling my hair out over here.

Comment: Hi, thinking out the box here. Have you installed the IIS HTTP Redirect module in IIS?

Answer (score 3):

You may need to install Application Request Routing, which is an extension to IIS and is available here: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in match regexp. It shouldn't start with slash. Correct is `^admin` (`^` means start of url)

```
<rule name="redirect">
    <match url="^admin" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="10.30.*.*" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/error" />
</rule>
```

And i have couple of notes:

1) For IP validation better to have regexp like that: `10.30.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}` instead of `10.30.*.*`

2) Depends on your load balancer and network infrastructure, but you might need to check `{HTTP_X_Forwarded_For}` header instead `{REMOVE_ADDR}`, because client's IP might be in different header